# google cloud project format --labelling

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training

Below is my script that prints the name,project id, org,space,zone in gcp. I am pretty sure other parts are good but erroring out in --> format("$ORG", ''),format("$SPACE", '') because not all projects have org, space and they are empty. how do I fix it by setting to N/A when they are empty.

```
  `echo 'project ' $COUNTER 'of' $TOTAL
  echo $project_id
  ORG=$(gcloud projects describe $project_id --format="get(labels.organization)")
  echo $ORG
  SPACE=$(gcloud projects describe $project_id --format="get(labels.space)")
  echo $SPACE
  gcloud compute instances list --project $project_id --format="csv(
   name,
   format("$ORG", ''),
   format("$SPACE", ''),
   zone.basename()
)" | awk 'NR>1' | sed s/$/,$project_id/
   >> $FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
`echo 'project ' $COUNTER 'of' $TOTAL
echo $project_id
ORG=$(gcloud projects describe project_id --format="get(labels.organization)")
if [ -z "$ORG" ]
then
        ORG="N/A"
fi
echo $ORG
SPACE=$(gcloud projects describe project_id --format="get(labels.space)")
if [ -z "$SPACE" ]
then
        SPACE="N/A"
fi
echo $SPACE
gcloud compute instances list --project $project_id --format="csv(
   name,
   format("$ORG", ''),
   format("$SPACE", ''),
   zone.basename()
)" | awk 'NR>1' | sed s/$/,$project_id/
   >> $FILE
```

Comment: Thanks Sergiusz. I am getting the output in the terminal and not to the csv as I wanted. How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you show example of what you want the output file to look like?

Comment: This comes on top of your code snippet above 

#!/usr/bin/env bash
PROJECTS=$(gcloud projects list --format='get(projectId)')
FILE="instances.csv"
rm $FILE
touch $FILE
START_TIME=$SECONDS
COUNTER=1
TOTAL=0
echo 'name,organization,space,zone,machine_type,preemptible,internal_ip,external_ip,status,service_account,project_id' >> $FILE
for project_id in $PROJECTS
do
  ((TOTAL=TOTAL+1))
done
for project_id in $PROJECTS
do

Comment: I will get name,organization,space,zone,machine_type,preemptible,internal_ip,external_ip,status,service_account,project_id as each column in csv and my script should print data in the respective columns after scraping thru my gcp.

Comment: You can use ```gcloud compute instances list --format="csv(name,organization,space,zone,machine_type,preemptible,internal_ip,external_ip,status,service_account,project_id)"``` but not all of those parameters can be obtained with this command. You can find more information about this command here - https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/list